# react-ace editor's onBlur event is not returning the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

```
<CodeEditor mode='python'
            width='100%'
            height='600px'
            value={'var x = 2;'}
            onBlur={(e, code) => this.onBlur(e, code)}/>
```

OnBlur function

```
onBlur(e, code) {
    console.log(code);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
```

e.target.value is ' ' even after writing code inside editor. Is there any way to get the code in onBlur? without using onChange???

Comment: `onBlur={(e, code) => this.onChange(e, code)}` This should your event call? isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, updated the question.

Comment: Does `e.target.value` return `""` every time or just when there is no text in text box?

Comment: returns "" every time.

Comment: I have read there code few times for this events issue. But I am not able to resolve it. I'll raise an issue on github @Amala James

Comment: they don't use the usual textarea to bind the events. To extract the value you would need to either use `refs` or set state on each keypress and then get the value of state onBlur.

Answer (score 1):

You can get react-ace-editor value on onBlur event like as below:

```js
onBlur(e, code) {
  const data = code.getValue();
  console.log('Editor Data: ',data);
}
```

I hope it would help you out.

Answer (score -1):

ReactAce doesn't appear to provide value of the editor, and `e.target` is the fake textarea used by ace which is empty, so you need a way to get the ace instance.

Something like this:

```
render = function() {
    var options = {};
    var reactAce; 
    return <div>          
        <ReactAce 
            style={{ height: '400px' }}
            ref={
                instance => { 
                    // store the ref to reactAce
                    reactAce = instance;
                }

            } 
            onBlur={
                (e)  =>  {
                    // get value of the editor
                    console.log(reactAce.editor.getValue());
                }
            }
          />
    </div>;
}
```